# Sonarqube Alert - New Major Issues since change previous analysis

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to create a notification in sonarqube (4.1.2) that will notify me whenever any new analysis found any new major issues. So I created an alert which is:

new major issues + change since previous analysis + is greater than 0 warning threshold and 0 error threshold

However I'm sometimes am not notify when there's a new major issue on the new analysis. I was wondering about how does this "new major issue" alert works?

Example:
I get major issue A and B in previous analysis. I rerun the analysis this time around after fixing A and B but I introduce major issue C. Will the new major issue be 1 (new major issue C) or -1 (C minus A and B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New issues metric (major or whatever severity) counts the added issues, not the differential. So in your example, you'll get 1.

So if you've set:

> new major issues + change since previous analysis + is greater than 0
>   warning threshold and 0 error threshold

, then you should see an alert in the dashboard of your project in that example.

Now, your question is about notification on alerts: this notification is sent when the alert level changes. So for example, when your project was OK (green) and passes to ERROR (red). In your example, this means that:

- if your project was OK and you add 1 issue, then you'll get a notification that your project turned to RED
- but if your project was always RED and you add 1 issue, then you'll get no notification because its alert level remains the same (RED)

Comment: But is it possible for Sonar to send a notification just for new major issues for any new analaysis without the need for the project to get to OK and Error?

Comment: This is what I understand so far:  

**For issues:**  
We will always get an email when there's an issue added, regardless major or minor.  

**For alerts:**  
We only will get an email if the status of the build changes (from green to red or vice versa) and we can filter it down with respect to the severity.   
**What we want:**   
We want sonar to send email only when the majer issues are introduced in current analysis, regardless the alert color from green to red or red to green. Is it possible?